# Google YouTube API: Playlists list and quotaExceeded

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have 120 playlists on YouTube and making below **[Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)** API call.

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=contentDetails,id,localizations,player,snippet,status&channelId=[CHANNEL_ID]&maxResults=50&key=[API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Initial two API calls succeed but intermittently third-get below error. If I rerun again the same story, success, and failure. I tried adding 30 seconds of sleep time between each call, but still the same story. I thought "***quotaExceeded***" happens when you cross 10,000 units each day but seems like I am missing anything. *Can someone please help?*

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.quota",
    "message" : "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>.",
    "reason" : "quotaExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>."
}
```

Comment: Are you using a valid/active API key instead of `&key=[API_KEY]` in your request?

Comment: Yes @sorifiend, I am using valid API key in my code.